# Detecting whole number with an "x" or "-" after using regex

Tags: regex, swift

I'm trying to use regex to detect the quantity in a list of items on a receipt. The software uses `OCR` so the return can vary a bit. To help ive narrowed it to assume that the quantity will always be at the start of the line and is always a whole number. The use cases I'm trying to cover are:

```
2 Burgers $4.00
2 x Burgers $4.00
2 X Burgers $4.00
2x Burgers $4.00
2X Burgers $4.00
2- Burgers $4.00
2 - Burgers $4.00
```

The plan is for the regex to return 2 for each example above. The regex I have so far is `\\d{1,2}(\\s[xX]|[xX])` this returns the top three examples fine but as much as I have tried I cant seem to get the rest detected, I haven't looked at adding the `-` yet as was stuck on detecting the `x` next to the Int.

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: Try `^\\d+(?=\\s*[xX-])`. Note that `^` matches the start of string, and if you need to match the start of a line, prepend the pattern with `(?m)`. If that number occurs at any location in the string, remove `^` altogether.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to match "only 1 or 2 digits"? What's wrong with `\\d+`, instead of `\\d{1,2}`?

Comment: You can use this as well. It will have the capture for your digit. 
^(\\d{1,2})\\s*[xX]*

Comment: @TomLord i believe i was trying to make it easier on myself if i had an example line like the following `"2 500ml 1664 êcole beer £8,000,000.0"` but @WiktorStribiżew has covered this.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Does it mean `\\d+(?=\\s*[xX-])` works for you? Your example in the comment suggests your real strings might differ from your simplified samples.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It does work yes, as its just finding any matches then picks the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To help ive narrowed it to assume that the quantity will always be at the start of the line and is always a whole number.

I suggest using something like

```
let pattern = "(?m)^\\d+"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PSSLPR/1).

The pattern will match 1 or more digits at the start of any line:

- `(?m)` - a MULTILINE modifier that makes `^` match the start of a line rather than the start of a string
- `^` - start of a line
- `\d+` - 1 or more (`+`) digits.

[image]

If you need to specify that some text should follow the digits, use a positive lookahead. E.g. you may require `x`/`X`/`-` after 0+ whitespaces, or a whitespace right after. Then, you need to use

```
let pattern = "(?m)\\d+(?=\\s*[xX-]|\\s)"
```

Here, `(?=\\s*[xX-]|\\s)` will make the regex match only those digits at the start of the line(s) that are immediately followed with either 0+ whitespace chars and then `X`, `x` or `-`, or that are immediately followed with a whitespace.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PSSLPR/2).

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\\d+)\\s?[xX-]?.*?([$£](?:\\d{1,2})(?:,?\\d{3})*\.?\\d{0,2})$
```

See it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/iv7ap3/1) (extra backslashes have been added in the code above to allow it to work in Swift, whereas the below link shows the expected result in JS, Python, Go and PHP, which means there are less backslashes there).

Will capture number of items and the price, what the item is is not captured.